# How to get the type of Paragraphs entity in the parent node field?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a "page" node with a paragraphs field `field-ref-para-multi` and the corresponding template `field--node--field-ref-para-multi--page.html.twig`.

And I have some paragraphs types that can be used in this field:

para_a

para_b

para_c

I have to place a surrounding html structure in the field depending of the paragraphs types that are used inside.

```
{# type a #}
<div class="js-para_a">
{% if multiple %}
    {% for item in items %}
        {{item.content}}
     {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for item in items %}
        {{item.content}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>

{# type b #}
<ul class="js-para_b">
{% if multiple %}
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>{{item.content}}</li>
     {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>{{item.content}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

But how to get the type of the used paragraphs in the field template?

Comment: This questions is referenced from d8cards, it deserves some upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can wrap each paragraphs field in any html wrapper of your choice, but you have to edit **each** field by modifying the appropriate `field.html.twig`  template file.

In the field template suggested name, for example:

`FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--paragraph--field-text-half--text-svg.html.twig
   x field--paragraph--field-text-half.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--text-svg.html.twig
   * field--field-text-half.html.twig
   * field--text-long.html.twig
   * field.html.twig`

You will then use the template suggested name to edit the `html` wrapper of your choice.

Like this :

```
{% if label_hidden %}
  {% if multiple %}
    <div{{ attributes }}>
      {% for item in items %}
        <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div> --> change div to preferred  html
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    <div{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</div>
    {% if multiple %}
      <div>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if multiple %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps :)